# Why does Perl's POSIX::strftime %F specifier not work on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, posix

I'm the author of the [Mac::PropertyList](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mac%3a%3aPropertyList) module which parses the Apple property list format. I've designed this to work across platforms, but I'm having trouble with [POSIX](http://www.metacpan.org/module/POSIX)'s `strftime` function which I use to create the date fields in the format that Apple specifies.

```
use POSIX; 
print 'Epoch is: ' . POSIX::strftime( "%FT%H:%M:%SZ\n", gmtime(978307200) );
```

On unix-like platforms, including darwin, this call produces the right sort of date:

```
2013-09-23T12:34:56Z
```

On Windows, it produces:

```
T12:34:56Z
```

This was reported as [CPAN RT #83460](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=83460). What's going on with Windows here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I was writing this question and researching everything, I found my own answer. I don't want all that work to go to waste though.

The `%F` format I used is not portable, and the [POSIX](http://www.metacpan.org/module/POSIX) module says so in its `strftime` entry:

```
If you want your code to be portable, your format ("fmt")
argument should use only the conversion specifiers defined by
the ANSI C standard (C89, to play safe).  These are
"aAbBcdHIjmMpSUwWxXyYZ%".
```

`%F` is really `%Y-%m-%d`, so I should use that.

My particular problem is that I know that the [POSIX](http://www.metacpan.org/module/POSIX) module tells you which format specifiers you can use to be portable, but I still have to look at the `strftime` man page to see what they do. In looking at the man page, I forget to check which ones are portable.