# Using POSIX::strftime vs. localtime + some custom formatting to generate a timestamp in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to generate a timestamp based on system time in perl in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format and currently using the POSIX module to do that:

```
require POSIX;
$timestamp = POSIX::strftime('%F %T', localtime);
```

There is an alternative to this which is a little more primitive:

```
my ($s,$min,$h,$d,$m,$y) = (localtime)[0..5];
$y += 1900;
$m   = sprintf('%.2d', ++$m);
$d   = sprintf('%.2d', $d);
$h   = sprintf('%.2d', $h);
$min = sprintf('%.2d', $min);
$s   = sprintf('%.2d', $s);
$timestamp = "$y-$m-$d $h:$min:$s";
```

All I need is to generate the timestamp in the above format but cannot decide which approach to use. This code is expected to run on multiple platforms (including Linux) and at a reasonably high frequency. I am thinking of using $^O to evaluate the OS name and using the former for Linux and latter for all else.

What are the benefits/drawbacks of each (other than more lines of code obviously). I'd be grateful if someone more knowledgeable in Perl could point me in the right direction. I have searched over the internet and perldocs but could not find the answer. It would be very helpful if someone can answer this directly or point me to a resource (website/blog/book) that could help me with this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If we clean up your code snippets and make them portable (by avoiding `%F` and `%T`), we get

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
my $timestamp = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime);
```

and

```
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $month, $year) = localtime;
my $timestamp = sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
   $year+1900, $month+1, $day, $hour, $min, $sec);
```

I would use the former because it's much simpler. This is true regardless of the OS.

Comment: Also, the `strftime` call is less error prone because you don't have to remember that quirky `+1900` and `+1` stuff.

Answer (score 3):

**This is an alternative solution** that uses the same underlying C library as the solutions [ikegami explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39646075/1331451). I have not done any benchmarking to see which one is faster or more efficient.

You can *also* use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece), which has been in core since Perl 5.10. It upgrades the return value of `localtime` to an object with handy methods. You can use those directly on the return value without assigning it to a variable.

```
use Time::Piece;
my $timestamp = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
   # Neither %F nor %T work on Windows.
```

Comment: `'%F %T` doesn't work with this for me either. But I don't think it's a wrapper. In https://metacpan.org/source/ESAYM/Time-Piece-1.31/Piece.pm#L613 it says _we don't want to load POSIX_. I'm trying to figure out how it works right now.

Comment: [Why does Perl's POSIX::strftime %F specifier not work on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18970859/176646) (neither `%F` nor `%T` is portable)

Comment: It doesn't use the POSIX version. It's built in C and attached with XS, and it loads a header file named _time.h_ [in Piece.xs](https://metacpan.org/source/ESAYM/Time-Piece-1.31/Piece.xs#L8).

Comment: That doesn't contradict what I said. In fact, I just confirmed the guess I had previously stated: `%F` and `%T` as supported by neither POSIX nor Time::Piece because `POSIX::strftime` and `Time::Piece`'s `strftime` both call the same function (C's `strftime`). That makes `use Time::Piece;
my $timestamp = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');` nothing more than a more complex version of `use POSIX qw( strftime );
my $timestamp = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime);`.